# FATAL EXCEPTION: main, Error inflating class fragment, android.view.InflateException

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

I am trying to make a map application. Using a button to link to the MapActivity class but the application crashes immediately when I press the button. Please advise, if more information is needed to solve the error please feel free to request from me.

MapActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map); //<-- logcat points at this line

    }
```

activity_map

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">



    <include layout="@layout/content_map" /> //<-- this is line 12



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MapActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_map"*>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ripple_bg"
        app:rb_color="#0099CC"
        app:rb_radius="32dp"
        app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
        app:rb_duration="3000"
        app:rb_scale="6">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:translationY="-18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_placeholder"/>
    </com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>
    <com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
        style="@style/MaterialSearchBarLight"
        app:mt_speechMode="false"
        app:mt_hint="Search a place"
        app:mt_maxSuggestionsCount="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchBar"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:mt_navIconEnabled="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        app:mt_placeholder="Search a place"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_find"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Find Restaurants"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlMRH.png)
[Continue from logcat1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfkZd.png)

Comment: build gradle dependencies{
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
}

Comment: content_map, relative layout has a * at the opening tag.

Comment: i think accidentally added it when im posting the question sorry i will edit the post

Comment: what is the exact exception message?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.superapp/com.example.superapp.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.superapp:layout/activity_map: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.superapp:layout/content_map: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: if you want to inflate fragment you'd go use LayoutInflater(...) or a reference to the root.inflate(...), what is the type of main activity, fragment?

Comment: give please full stacktrace of error message

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ
arrr I see thanks for the advise,
My main_activity is a drawerlayout

Comment: @Kirguduck I placed the full trace with the image attached Logcat and Continue from locat1. Are there any additional logs that I can trace? o.o

Comment: @prozai sorry did not notice your links. and what is the line 80 of your MapActivity? and how and where do you inflate your fragment @+id/map ?

Comment: Did you add     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your full stack trace, you didn't input your API keys in your Manifest. Put the following into the manifest, under `<application>` tag.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value=" your key here" />
```

Follow the guide here for API key set up

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

Comment: thank you so much I did not realise that. I was attaching my api key inside my string file but not in the meta data.